# SSL over differents servers/ips

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I have an website hosted on one server, accessible by WWW with ssl installed
And another one hosting with non-www, if try to enter on it, it will redirect to the one with ssl and WWW.

Now is the problem, when i access the website with SSL, chrome says something is wrong with the ssl certificate, firefox doesnt!

What am i doing wrong? I already tried with some tools and everything is fine, only the difference is the 2 servers.

If you want the link to test, i can send.

check image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JGUm.png

Comment: Please add the real error message instead of "...something is wrong". And check the server against [sslabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Comment: i added the image on original post already, please check.

Answer (score 0):

This site receives a grade F with [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=lewe.com.br&s=187.102.40.17).

There are multiple issues with this site. I don't speak portuguese, but I think the information you get might be related to the weak signature used for the certificate.